# How to style html layout with double sidebars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a layout with a double sided bar. Left bar and right bar. I've tried solving it with the html/css below. below is the code could someone  help me  out.
[example of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvG5M.png)

**CSS code below**

```
    #wrap {
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      width: 700px;
      border: 3px solid black;
      background-color: grey;
      height: 700px;
      padding: 10px
    }

    #header {
      margin: auto;
      background-color: white;
      height: 70px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #left {
      margin: auto;
      width: 150px;
      height: 70%;
      background-color: white;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #content{
      background-color: red;
    }

    #right {
      margin: auto;
      width: 150px;
      height: 70%;
      background-color: white;
      float: right;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #footer {
      margin: auto;
      height: 10%;
      background-color: blue;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
        <p>header will be here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="left">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content here
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p> name and address here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p> copyright </p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: That's called the **Holy Grail** Layout....just google it...there's *hundreds* of solutions.

Comment: Thanks buddy it really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called the **Holy Grail Layout** and it's been easily solved with Flexbox

```css
#wrap {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.center {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  padding: 10px;
}
#content {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1
}
#right {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #c0ffee;
  padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <p>header will be here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="left">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      content here
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <p>name and address here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>copyright</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. Really helped.